# Remove data between two words in a string

Tags: r, regex

My data looks like this:

```
x = "Unable to load the file //xxxx/yyy/abc.pdf onto the RAM"
```

I need to space out the data between "file" and "onto", and need output something like this

```
"Unable to load the file onto the RAM"
```

I tried `rm_between` option from `qdapRegex` package, but this removes even words "file" and "onto" when I try something like this:

`rm_between(x,"file","onto",replacement = "")`

I couldnt find any other option that retains the boundary words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions (regex) and base R function `gsub()` can do the job:

```
gsub("(?<=file).*(?=onto)", " ", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "Unable to load the file onto the RAM"
```

The regex trick we use is *positive* *lookahead* and *lookbehind*.

An alternative:

```
gsub("(file).*(onto)", "\\1 \\2", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "Unable to load the file onto the RAM"
```

Also a simple trick to continue using the function you have been using is:

```
qdapRegex::rm_between(x, "file", "onto", replacement = "file onto")
[1] "Unable to load the file onto the RAM"
```

Taking a look at the documentation there is also an argument not to remove the boundaries (markers), which leads to the simplest solution:

```
qdapRegex::rm_between(x, "file", "onto", replacement = " ", include.markers = FALSE)
[1] "Unable to load the file onto the RAM"
```